# Passing multidimensional arrays as arguments in functions in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, cs50

I am currently doing the fifteen exercise in CS50's Problem set 3. However, I am stuck in figuring out the syntax to pass a multi-dimensional array as an argument to a function. For instance, the following code (which prints out some numbers in an array) compiles and works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int array[], int size);

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    int array[3] = {1,2,3};
    func(array,size);
    printf("Done\n");
}

void func(int array[], int size)
{
    printf("%i %i %i\n", array[0],array[1], array[2]);
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int array[][], int size);

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    int array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    func(array,size);
    printf("Done");
}

void func(int array[][], int size)
{
    printf("%i %i %i\n", array[0][0],array[1][1], array[2][2]);
}
```

This is the error provided by clang:

```
test.c:3:20: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void func(int array[][], int size);
                   ^
test.c:13:20: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void func(int array[][], int size)
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with my syntax? I don't quite understand the error messages given to me by clang.

Comment: `int array[2][2] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` is just wrong, use `int array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` (you're declaring an array of 3 `int[3]` arrays. arrays decay into pointers when passed to functions, so you're passing an argument of the type `int (*)[]` (pointer to an array of ints), not an `int[]` or `int *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `func()` expects a *pointer to int* but you are passing a *pointer to an array*. Hence, the errrors.
It's because an array gets converted into a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function.

You can change the function prototype and definition to receive a pointer to an array:

```
void func(int (*array)[3], int size);

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    int array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    func(array,size);
    printf("Done");
}

void func(int (*array)[3], int size) {
  ...
}
```

Note that your array is initialized with size 3x3. So the array size has to 3x3 at least.

---

C99 allows to you pass dimensions. So you can write it like this too:

```
void func(int x, int y, int a[x][y]);

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    int array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    func(3, 3, array);
    printf("Done");
}

void func(int x, int y, int array[x][y])
{
    printf("%i %i %i\n", array[0][0],array[1][1], array[2][2]);
}
```

Comment: Since the rule for function parameters is that "array of type will decay into pointer to type, pointing at first element", I think it is more readable to declare the parameter as `int array[3][3]`. It will decay into a pointer to first element `int(*)[3]` anyhow.

Comment: I always write what it is i.e. `void func( int *a) {..}` not `void func( int a[]) {..}` despite both of them are equivalent. I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Specifying the inner-most dimension has one advantage though: it creates self-documenting code saying "this function will handle a 3x3 array", which is more specific. It could also help with static analysis beyond what's required of the C compiler - suppose someone passes a 4x3 array to the function. A static code analyser could then tell that something is fishy, which it wouldn't be able to otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question, when I try to create the array in main by doing `int array[size][size] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};`, I get an error saying ` error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`. Why is that so?

Comment: @WetFeet 1) You need a C99 compiler. E.g. With gcc you can do with `gcc -std=c99 file.c`. 2) You can't *initialize* a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You can define it: `int size = 3; int a[size][size];` and then use a loop to assign values.

Answer (score 1):

An array is not a type in C! Internally, it is always handled as a pointer, hence, a pointer to the array is passed as argument and not the array itself.

If you intend to pass arrays as arguments (and not just pointers), you should rethink your design!

If you still need to do this wrap the array into a structure and pass the structure.

```
struct astruct
{
   int size;
   int array[3];
};
```

Comment: You may read my article on this topic which explains the problem and the solution in detail: [Passing Arrays in C](https://www.cypherpunk.at/2016/01/passing-arrays-as-parameter-in-c/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify size of array *when declaring prototype as well as while defining function* . Right now it is of incomplete type .

Try this instead -

```
void func(int array[][3], int size)
```

Answer (score 0):

A declaration like `int a[][]` isn't sensible, since the compiler must know the size of all dimensions (except of the outermost) to calculate the memory address on access.

I.e. if an array is declared as

```
int array[][a][b];
```

The memory address for access to

```
array[2][1][3];
```

is calculated by

```
base_address + (2*a*b + 1*b + 3) * sizeof int
```

Without knowing a and/or b, this calculation would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply tell the function to expect a multi-dimensional array:

```
void func (int array[3][3], int size);
```

Or if you want the function to be completely flexible:

```
void func (int x, int y, int array[x][y]);
```